# I want to upload multiple files using dropzone.js but getting error

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js for uploading multiple files but getting error as following while upload

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL /file-upload was not found on this server.</p><p>Additionally,
a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p><hr><address>Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 Server at localhost Port 80</address></body></html>
```

I don't what is the problem I copy the same code from codepen but getting an error please help me thank you in advance.

Comment: can u put more info like code etc to debug.

Comment: https://codepen.io/probil/pen/yyzdOM

Comment: this is the link from where i copied the code

Comment: u should add url in dropzone initialization

Comment: how to add url ?

Comment: even if you upload images in codepen example then after uploading it gives error message not found.

Comment: $(function(){
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 5,
    ....
    url: /url_to_upload_file,

    init:function(){
      ...
    }
  };
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put url in initialization

```
$(function(){
      Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        maxFilesize: 5,
        ....
        url: /url_to_upload_file,

        init:function(){
          ...
        }
      };
    })
```

Comment: $(function(){
  Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 5,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
      url: /images/,
    dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
    acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
    init:function(){

Comment: still, same error is there any need of any backend code for this because i am only doing front-end I did not write any code in the backend .

Comment: you should write backend code. Once you upload file it will hit the url in server that you mentioned as url in initialization.Otherwise it will throw error and u see red as progress bar in file.

Comment: thank you, i think I should have write backend code.